# Debounce on one Observable in merge

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following merge(), where I merge the events to send a single request to my API:

```
merge(
  this.sort.sortChange,
  this.paginator.page,
  this.statusSelect.selectionChange,
  this.searchFilterEvent$
)
```

Now, the first three arguments are the events emitted by Angular Material Directives, the last `this.searchFilterEvent$` is an Observable created from `fromEvent` which is the keyup event on an input. I want that on each event (except the searchFilterEvent) the code below is executed, but have a debounceTime only on the searchEventFilter, so that I don't send a request on every keyup event.
Is that possible or do I have to separate them and write the code that's executed on the events twice (or in a function and call the function of course)?

Comment: You just chain `this.searchFilterEvent$.pipe(debounceTime(...))` and leave the rest as is.

Comment: Really? I'm feeling really stupid right now, getting blinded from coding all day. Thank you very much! How should I deal with the SO question now tho? Could you write this as a simple answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just chain the one Observable with `debounceTime` and leave the rest as is:

```
merge(
  this.sort.sortChange,
  this.paginator.page,
  this.statusSelect.selectionChange,
  this.searchFilterEvent$.pipe(debounceTime(...)),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for making it an answer! I should check out the documentation of rxjs again to feel more comfortable with it's useage.